# Best way to wire this ring cam?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I have this light box with 6 wires coming out from two channels. The top has red, yellow and white with black stripe. The lower channel has black, white and bare wire.

[image]

The ring cam has a green/yellow, black and white wire.

[image]

I have already tried connecting the cam to the lower channel with black to black, white to white and green/yellow to bare on ground screw with no success. The cam just didn’t power on. Then I tried the upper channel with white to white/black stripe, black to red and yellow/green to yellow on ground screw which was a mistake as sparks flew out of the gear box. I don’t see any damage and everything seems to be working properly but it was indeed an error. I’m now waiting on a voltage tester to check every wire but I’m wondering if anyone has insight given the information provided above.

The switch has red yellow and black switch connected. Image below.

[image]

Comment: US wire colors, except for white (usually) neutral and green (ground) and bare (ground) are largely unpredictable. Was the original light on a switch? If so, what happened to the switch?

Comment: How was everything connected before you pulled it all apart?

Comment: We need to know how the switch is wired with pics - thanks

Comment: @DJ. Pic of switch wiring provided.

Comment: Good news: You've got conduit, so changing wiring (if necessary) is easy! Bad news: the switch on the left has 2 black wires wrapped around a screw that's not listed for having 2 wires on it. That needs to be pigtailed (use a 3-port Wago) with a separate wire to each switch. Which switch controlled the light up there? Were there 2 separately controlled lights?

Comment: Did you make any wiring changes at all at the switch box? As an alternative to my suggestion above, just take the black wire from the right switch off of the left switch and put it in the 5-port Wago with the other blacks and the one red.

Comment: @FreeMan yes, this outlet controls the outside wall light and an indoor ceiling fan which I provided pics for. I currently have another post regarding this fan if more info is needed. 

The left switch only needs to control the outside light. Would it be okay to disconnect both switches so they work independently. I have identified which black, white, and yellow wires run to the electric box outside where the ring cam will go. No changes to the switch box were made.

Comment: This isn't an outlet. It's a junction box with 2 switches mounted. An "outlet" or "receptacle" is a device into which you plug a cord. Knowing proper terms will help simplify communication in the future. You say outlet and 99.999% of people will see something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Tamper-Resistant-Duplex-Outlet-White-10-Pack-M22-T5320-WMP/100684043) in their heads.

Comment: Also, you mention "channel" in your post about the things in that first pic. Those are actually "conduit", not "channel". There is "channel" appropriate for electrical wiring, but this isn't it. Again, just trying to help you communicate more clearly.

Comment: @FreeMan great good to know. So can I disconnect the black wire from the right switch all together? How would connect the ring cam outside? My guess is red to black(cam), black to white(cam), bare to yellow/green(cam) to ground screw?

Answer (score 2):

The most bizarre thing to me is all the wiring at the outdoor(?) junction box where you're planning on mounting the camera. It looks like it was fed from more that one circuit/switch. I think you'll really need to wait until you get your meter in and do some testing to see what's what.

With power on, turn on one switch, then with the meter *carefully* (remember you're working with line voltage here, possibly on a ladder, the shock *could* kill you), measure pairs of wires.

You'd want to measure the black against the ground from the lower group to see if you get 120v with *that* switch on. If not, start measuring the different colored wires from the top group against to see which one is giving you a 120v reading.

Once you identify the wire that is giving you power, turn the breaker back off, then wire your camera to that hot, neutral, ground set. Put individual wire nuts (or 2-port Wagos) on all the other wires so that they're each individually insulated, stuff all those unused wires into the back of the box and mount the Ring to the wall.

---

At the switch box, you have 2 black wires under one screw on the left-hand switch. This switch isn't rated for 2 wires on one screw. Back the screw out enough to get the wire that's jumpered to the right switch out, then tighten that screw back down.

Take that jumper wire, straighten the end out, and stick it in the 5-port Wago that already has 3 black and 1 red wire in it.

This *should* continue to provide unswitched power to everything that needs power while eliminating the code violation and possible cause of a fire.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to figure out. The wires from both the switch for the ceiling fan and the wall lamp were routed towards the junction box outside where the ring cam was install thus why there were so many wire coming from this box. Three of these wires for the wall lamp and three for the ceiling lamp so after figuring out which wire corresponded to what switch and some wiring, both the camera and the ceiling were connected and are working properly. Apologies if there are any errors in the terminology.

Comment: Very odd that the (indoor?) _ceiling fan_ wiring was routed through an outside box. But, I'm glad you got it sorted.